# How to translate XPath into Restassured xmlPath equivalent?

Tags: xpath, groovy, gpath

Does anyone know how to make following Xpath expression

`someRoot.children3.someLeaf[not(children3)]/@_uri`

to work with `io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath#get`? XmlPath is using `GPath`  but im an not familiar with it at all. Quoting:

"It follows the Groovy [GPath](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gpath) syntax  * described [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_manipulating_xml)"